# Block with Listing of custom links to redirect to pages

Tags: 8, blocks

With Drupal 8 I want to have a block with a select list that I get programmatically from taxonomy terms and when the user clicks on Submit it redirects the user to the page I put in the list.  What is the best way to achieve this? Should I make a custom block with the code for the select inside or is there a module that does this  I looked at jump menu but doesn't look like what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_jump_menu to create a select list from my taxonomy terms, and put it in a views block.